# make nested mongodb queries faster

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This function triggers on getinitialprops which waits for it to finish before render. Is there any way to gain speed versus waiting for this long query to finish?

```
exports.getAppStats = (req, res, next) => {
  const startToday = moment(req.query.today).startOf('day');
  const endToday = moment(req.query.today).endOf('day');
  const startsevenDays = moment(req.query.today).subtract(7, 'd').startOf('day');
  const startThirtyDays = moment(req.query.today).subtract(30, 'd').startOf('day');
  const startYear = moment(req.query.today).subtract(365, 'd').startOf('day');

  const stats = {}
  Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startToday, $lte: endToday } })
    .then((result) => {
      stats.today = result
      Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startsevenDays, $lte: endToday } })
      .then((result) => {
        stats.sevenDays = result
        Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startThirtyDays, $lte: endToday } })
        .then((result) => {
          stats.thirtyDays = result
          Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startYear, $lte: endToday } })
          .then((result) => {
            stats.year = result
            return res.json(stats);
          }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where you can leverage the [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function to run all of your queries in parallel and then wait until all of them are finished, like so:

```
exports.getAppStats = (req, res, next) => {
  const startToday = moment(req.query.today).startOf('day');
  const endToday = moment(req.query.today).endOf('day');
  const startsevenDays = moment(req.query.today).subtract(7, 'd').startOf('day');
  const startThirtyDays = moment(req.query.today).subtract(30, 'd').startOf('day');
  const startYear = moment(req.query.today).subtract(365, 'd').startOf('day');

  const stats = {}
  // get promises for each query
  let today = Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startToday, $lte: endToday } });
  let sevenDays = Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startsevenDays, $lte: endToday } });
  let thirtyDays = Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startThirtyDays, $lte: endToday } });
  let year = Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startYear, $lte: endToday } });
  // wait until all promises have been resolved, then set stats & send response
  Promise.all([today, sevenDays, thirtyDays, year]).then(([todayData, sevenDaysData, thirtyDaysData, yearData]) => {
    stats = {
      today: todayData,
      sevenDays: sevenDaysData,
      thirtyDays: thirtyDaysData,
      year: yearData
    }
    res.status(200).json({data: stats});
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    // next(err);
    // res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong..." });
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `async/await` keywords to avoid callbacks, altogether. Although it will require a `try/catch` to handle errors. Honestly it makes no difference, it's purely preference.

```
// note this is now an async function
exports.getAppStats = async (req, res, next) => {
  const startToday = moment(req.query.today).startOf('day');
  const endToday = moment(req.query.today).endOf('day');
  const startsevenDays = moment(req.query.today).subtract(7, 'd').startOf('day');
  const startThirtyDays = moment(req.query.today).subtract(30, 'd').startOf('day');
  const startYear = moment(req.query.today).subtract(365, 'd').startOf('day');

  // get promises for each query
  let today = Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startToday, $lte: endToday } });
  let sevenDays = Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startsevenDays, $lte: endToday } });
  let thirtyDays = Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startThirtyDays, $lte: endToday } });
  let year = Application.countDocuments({ dateTime: { $gte: startYear, $lte: endToday } });
  try {
    // wait until all promises have been resolved, then set stats & send response
    // await Promise.all instead of using callbacks
    let [todayData, sevenDaysData, thirtyDaysData, yearData] = await Promise.all(
      [today, sevenDays, thirtyDays, year]
    );
    let stats = {
      today: todayData,
      sevenDays: sevenDaysData,
      thirtyDays: thirtyDaysData,
      year: yearData
    }
    res.status(200).json({data: stats});
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    // next(err);
    // res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong..." });
  }
}
```